# How to prevent Eclipse from closing opened files that no longer exist

Tags: eclipse

If you have a file that exists open in Eclipse, and then have that file externally moved, renamed, deleted, etc., Eclipse will automatically close the file as soon as focus returns to it in the editor. Is there a way to prevent this from happening, so that the file is kept open? Other editors have a dialog window that says something like *"This file no longer exists. Would you like to close it?"*

Comment: I have the same issue with Eclipse 4.6.2 (Neon). When I repeated this a few times, the automatic error reporting feature of eclipse popped up and showed me an exception, and referred me to [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=466379). This is obviously a bug in eclipse. Upvoting it in bugzilla might help solving it.

Comment: This bug is fixed now but it still closes editors of deleted files.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus I've since abandoned Eclipse for PHPStorm.